# How to use BitmapFont.TextBounds to center a line of text on the screen?

Tags: java, bitmap, libgdx

The code I'm using to center these two lines of text are not working. [Here](http://tinypic.com/r/35ldu1j/8) is the link of what it looks like on my screen, [LINK](http://tinypic.com/r/35ldu1j/8)

Here is the code I used to do that, and I want both of the texts to be centered horizontally on the screen.

```
    BitmapFont.TextBounds titleBounds1 = font.getBounds("Pizza Delivery");
    BitmapFont.TextBounds titleBounds2 = font.getBounds("MADNESS");

    font.draw(batch,"Pizza Delivery", (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - titleBounds1.width)  / 2,500);
    font.draw(batch,"MADNESS",(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - titleBounds2.width)  / 2, 450);
```

Comment: You could use a `Table` for that and add the text as `Label`s.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is fine, so it must be something else in code that you haven't posted.

As far as I can see, the only thing that would cause the effect your getting is if the batch has had a scale applied to it.

If that's the case then there are two possible solutions

1. Factor in the scale when calculating the center positions
2. If the scaling is solely for the text, then don't scale the batch, use font.setScale() instead, and do it before getting the bounds.